# Linq to Sql has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I get `Linq to Sql has no supported translation to SQL` on the line below. Maybe someone could explain how this can be solved?

```
UsersCount = _repository.GetUsers(p.Id).Count()
```

Full code

```
public IQueryable<ProductViewModel> Build()
{
 return _repository.GetProducts(true).Select(p=> new ProductViewModel
   {
  Id = p.Id, 
  Name = p.Name,
  UsersCount = _repository.GetUsers(p.Id).Count()
   });         
}


public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
    return _db.Orders.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId)
                     .SelectMany(t1 => _db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == t1.UserId)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(), (order, user) => user);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is not correct with your function. The `SelectMany` will return null if there is no user becuase you are using `DefaultIfEmpty()`. That indicates that you want to do a `left join`. But the function return users. So this might be a way for you:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
    return (
        from o in _db.Orders
        from u in _db.User.Where(a=>a.Id==o.UserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where o.ProductId==productId
        select u
    );
}
```

I would expect a function to return user when the GetUsers is called. So something like this then:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
     return (
        from o in _db.Orders
        join u in _db.User
            on o.UserId equals u.Id 
        where o.ProductId==productId
        select u
    );
}
```

Or if orders is a one to many table and you want unique users. Then something like this:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
    return (
        from o in _db.Orders
        where _db.Users.Select(a=>a.Id).Contains(o.UserId)
        where o.ProductId==productId
        select u
    );
}
```

I am not really sure what you want. But i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Code is not clear but it looks like you are trying to use LINQ2SQL like you would use SQL and not relying on LINQ2SQL to do the joins for you. Main confusion here is `GetUsers` method which I suspect should return users for given order on given product ID. If I'm getting it correct this method should look more like this:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
    IQueryable<User> users = from order in _db.Orders
                             where order.ProductId == productId
                             select order.users;
    return users;
}
```

For this to work you must have table relationships defined in you database and imported into DBML file along with all table definitions. Having relationships defined in DB (thus inside LINQ2SQL) is a much better approach than specifying them in code each time you do a query. Your LINQ queries will be a lot simpler. And it helps to keep database data integrity.